# Having problems feeding data to tensorflow graph

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to adjust the MNIST2 problem in tensorflow tutorial to train a neural network using my own images. But I am having problems feeding data to the graph.

```
My code:
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
import time

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import mnist

# Basic model parameters as external flags.
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_epochs', 2, 'Number of epochs to run trainer.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 100, 'Batch size.')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', '/root/data', 'Directory with the training data.')

# Constants used for dealing with the files, matches convert_to_records.
TRAIN_FILE = 'train.tfrecords'
VALIDATION_FILE = 'validation.tfrecords'


# Set-up dos pacotes
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      dense_keys=['image_raw', 'label'],
      # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
      dense_types=[tf.string, tf.int64])
    # Convert from a scalar string tensor (whose single string has
  # length mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS) to a uint8 tensor with shape
  # [mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS].

  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image.set_shape([mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS])

  # OPTIONAL: Could reshape into a 28x28 image and apply distortions
  # here.  Since we are not applying any distortions in this
  # example, and the next step expects the image to be flattened
  # into a vector, we don't bother.

  # Convert from [0, 255] -> [-0.5, 0.5] floats.
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5

  # Convert label from a scalar uint8 tensor to an int32 scalar.
  label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)

  return image, label


def inputs(train, batch_size, num_epochs):
  """Reads input data num_epochs times.
  Args:
    train: Selects between the training (True) and validation (False) data.
    batch_size: Number of examples per returned batch.
    num_epochs: Number of times to read the input data, or 0/None to
       train forever.
  Returns:
    A tuple (images, labels), where:
    * images is a float tensor with shape [batch_size, 30,26,1]
      in the range [-0.5, 0.5].
    * labels is an int32 tensor with shape [batch_size] with the true label,
      a number in the range [0, char letras).
    Note that an tf.train.QueueRunner is added to the graph, which
    must be run using e.g. tf.train.start_queue_runners().
  """
  if not num_epochs: num_epochs = None
  filename = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir,
                          TRAIN_FILE if train else VALIDATION_FILE)

  with tf.name_scope('input'):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        [filename], num_epochs=num_epochs)

    # Even when reading in multiple threads, share the filename
    # queue.
    image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

    # Shuffle the examples and collect them into batch_size batches.
    # (Internally uses a RandomShuffleQueue.)
    # We run this in two threads to avoid being a bottleneck.
    images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
        capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,
        # Ensures a minimum amount of shuffling of examples.
        min_after_dequeue=1000)

    return images, sparse_labels

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

#Variaveis
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 36])


#Layer 1
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

#Layer 2
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

#Densely Connected Layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

#Dropout - reduz overfitting
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

#Readout layer
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 36])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([36])
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

#Train and evaluate
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)


for i in range(20000):
  batch = inputs(train=True, batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size, num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)
  if i%100 == 0:
    print (batch[0])
    print (type(batch[0]))
    print (tf.shape(batch[0],name=None))
    a=np.reshape(batch[0],(100,784))
    #batch[1]=np.reshape(batch[1],[1])    
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

test = inputs(train=False, batch_size=2000)
print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: test[0], y_: test[1], keep_prob: 1.0}))

coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

The program outputs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4_Treino_Rede_Neural.py", line 158, in <module>
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 460, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2910, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 357, in run
    np_val = np.array(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_t.dtype.as_numpy_dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue.
Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks
Marcelo V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to feed the `feed_dict` argument with TensorFlow tensors. TensorFlow then tries to convert these `tf.Tensor` to numpy arrays but cannot and returns your error.

As you use an input queue, you don't need a `feed_dict`.

Instead of:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 36])
```

Just use:

```py
x, y_ = inputs(train=True, batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size, num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!, just to confim
I have to do the following modifications:
1) Remove x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]) 
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 36])
2) Replace
batch = inputs(train=True, batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size, num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)
by
x, y_ = inputs(train=True, batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size, num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)
3)Replace
train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
by
train_accuracy = accuracy.eval()
train_step.run()

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you replace the lines `x = tf.placeholder(...)` and `y_ = tf.placeholder(...)` by this line: `x, y_ = inputs(train=True, ...)` because you will **need** `x` and `y_` in your graph.

Comment: When using `sess.run()`, you just need to provide `keep_prob` in your `feed_dict`.

Comment: Does one have to use the `inputs(..)` in the for loop? @OlivierMoindrot I have got a similar problem here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983754/separate-validation-and-training-graph-when-using-queues-to-feed-data-to-network/43987474?noredirect=1#comment75052761_43987474)

Comment: @thigi you're using a queue in your example, which is very different

Comment: Could you help me out anyway? I thought queues is a necessity for big datasets? But it seems like everyone is using feed_dict. Maybe I will downgrade to feed_dict as well @OlivierMoindrot

Comment: @thigi : Using queues is better in fact. Someone seems to have answered you extensively in your other thread.