# Separate Validation and Training Graph when using queues to feed data to network in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been doing lots of research regarding how to use the queues for feeding the data to the network properly. However, I could not find any solutions on the internet.

Currently my code is able to read the training data and perform training, but without validation and testing. Here some important lines form my code:

```
images, volumes = utils.inputs(FLAGS.train_file_path, FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.num_epochs)

print("Initiliaze training")
logits = utils.inference(images)
loss_intermediate, loss = utils.get_loss(logits, volumes)

train_optimizer = utils.pre_training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)

summary_train = tf.summary.merge_all('train')
summary_test = tf.summary.merge_all('test')

init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)
with tf.Session() as sess:

    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir + FLAGS.run, sess.graph)
    summary_writer_test = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir + FLAGS.run_test, sess.graph)
    sess.run(init)

    # Start input enqueue threads.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    print("Start training")

    try:
        step = 0
        while not coord.should_stop():
            start_time = time.time()

            _, loss_intermediate_value, loss_value = sess.run([train_optimizer, loss_intermediate, loss])
            duration = time.time() - start_time
            if step % FLAGS.show_step == 0:
                print('Step %d: loss_intermediate = %.2f, loss = %.5f (%.3f sec)' % (step, loss_intermediate_value, loss_value, duration))
                summary_str = sess.run(summary_train)
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
                summary_writer.flush()

            if step % FLAGS.test_interval == 0:
               ###### HERE VALIDATION HOW ? ############
            step += 1
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('ERROR IN CODE')
    finally:
        print('Done training for %d epochs, %d steps.' % (FLAGS.num_epochs, step))
        # When done, ask the threads to stop.
        coord.request_stop()
        # Wait for threads to finish.
        coord.join(threads)
```

And this function is used to read the data.

```
def inputs(train, batch_size, num_epochs):

  if not num_epochs: num_epochs = None
  filename = os.path.join(train)

  with tf.name_scope('input'):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=num_epochs)

    image, volume = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

    images, volumes = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, volume], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2, capacity=1000 * batch_size, min_after_dequeue=500)

    return images, volume
```

I do not understand how to use tensor flow to create another input queue or input graph to do validation. Can someone help me? Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

```
def _conv(self, inputs, nb_filter, kernel_size=1, strides=1, pad='VALID', name='conv'):
        with tf.name_scope(name) as scope:

            #kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([kernel_size, kernel_size,int(inputs.get_shape().as_list()[3]),int(nb_filter)], mean=0.0, stddev=0.0001), name='weights')
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False)([kernel_size, kernel_size,int(inputs.get_shape().as_list()[3]),int(nb_filter)]), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, kernel, [1,strides,strides,1], padding=pad, data_format='NHWC')
            return conv
```

**EDIT 2**

```
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    print("Load Data...")
    images, volumes = utils.inputs(FLAGS.train_file_path, FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.num_epochs)
    v_images, v_volumes = utils.inputs(FLAGS.val_file_path, FLAGS.batch_size)

    print("input shape: " + str(images.get_shape()))
    print("output shape: " + str(volumes.get_shape()))

    print("Initialize training")
    logits = utils.inference(images, FLAGS.stacks, True)
    v_logits = utils.inference(v_images, FLAGS.stacks, False)

    tf.add_to_collection("logits", v_logits)

    loss = utils.get_loss(logits, volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'train')
    v_loss = utils.get_loss(v_logits, v_volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'val')

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        train_optimizer = utils.pre_training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)

    validate = utils.validate(v_images, v_logits, v_volumes, FLAGS.scale)

    summary_train_op = tf.summary.merge_all('train')
    summary_val_op = tf.summary.merge_all('val')

    init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir + FLAGS.run, sess.graph)
        summary_writer_val = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir + FLAGS.run + FLAGS.run_val, sess.graph)
        sess.run(init)

        # Start input enqueue threads.
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        try:
            print("Start training")
            step = 0
            while not coord.should_stop():

                start_time = time.time()
                _, loss_list, image_batch, volume_batch, summary_str = sess.run([train_optimizer, loss, images, volumes, summary_train_op])
                duration = time.time() - start_time

                if (step + 1) % FLAGS.show_step == 0:
                    print('Step %d: (%.3f sec)' % (step, duration), end= ': ')
                    print (", ".join('%.5f'%float(x) for x in loss_list))
                    summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)

                if (step + 1) % FLAGS.val_interval == 0:

                    val_loss_sum_list = [0] * len(v_loss)

                    for val_step in range(0, FLAGS.val_iter):
                        _, val_loss_list, summary_str_val, image_input, volume_estimated, volume_ground_truth = sess.run([validate, v_loss, summary_val_op, v_images, v_logits, v_volumes])
                        val_loss_sum_list = [sum(x) for x in zip(val_loss_sum_list, val_loss_list)]

                        if (val_step + 1) == FLAGS.val_iter:
                            print('Validation Interval %d: ' % (step / FLAGS.val_interval), end= '')
                            print (", ".join('%.5f'%float(x / FLAGS.val_iter) for x in val_loss_sum_list))
                            summary_writer_val.add_summary(summary_str_val, step)

                            #image_input, volume_estimated, volume_ground_truth = sess.run([v_images, v_logits, v_volumes])
                            #summary_val_images_op = utils.validate(image_input, volume_estimated, volume_ground_truth, FLAGS.scale, int(step / FLAGS.val_interval))

                if (step + 1) % FLAGS.step_save_checkpoint == 0:
                    checkpoint_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir + FLAGS.run, 'hourglass-model')
                    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_file, global_step=step)
                    print('Step: ' + str(step))
                    print('Saved: ' + checkpoint_file)

                step += 1
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('OUT OF RANGE ERROR')
        except Exception as e:
            print(sys.exc_info())
            print('Unexpected error in code')
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
            print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        finally:
            print('Done training for %d epochs, %d steps.' % (FLAGS.num_epochs, step))
            checkpoint_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir + FLAGS.run, '-model')
            saver.save(sess, checkpoint_file, global_step=step)
            print('Step: ' + str(step))
            print('Saved: ' + checkpoint_file)

            # When done, ask the threads to stop.
            coord.request_stop()
            # Wait for threads to finish.
            coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: What i've done for a similar purpose but for reading from CSV files rather than images is to simply re-start the queue runners after the Training loop is over ant to point them at the Testing/Validation files. That sees to work well

Comment: Hm I want to do training whilst training tho! @VS_FF

Comment: ahh okok. Yes this way you do it only afterward

Comment: Do you have validation and test data sets? If yes, you just make a separate input queue for validation data using the same functions as you use for training and run your validation ops on it.

Comment: Yes I do, could you provide a code example? I honestly do not know what you mean. I have been reading a lot up on it and it seems to be very difficult to do so. @MadWombat

Comment: Well, your first line `images, volumes = utils.inputs(FLAGS.train_file_path, FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.num_epochs)` sets up the pipeline for your training data. You want to do the same for your validation data. Make it endless (set number of epochs to None in your input producer) and use the resulting batches to validate. I am not sure what problem you are having.

Comment: The problem is when I run `sess.run(..)`. How do I make sure that the validation data is used and not the test data? And would I need to use another queue? I am just really confused, but if it is so easy, would you mind questioning the answer via *Answer question* ? @MadWombat

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. Seems like there's no quick solution. A few have been proposed [here](http://engineering.taboola.com/more-than-one-graph-code-reuse-in-tensorflow/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you already have your data split into training and validation data sets, all you have to do is create another input pipeline for the validation data. Using the code you provided it should look something like this

```
images, volumes = utils.inputs(FLAGS.train_file_path, FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.num_epochs)
# create validation pipeline
v_images, v_volumes = utils.inputs(FLAGS.valid_file_path, FLAGS.batch_size, None)

logits = utils.inference(images)
loss_intermediate, loss = utils.get_loss(logits, volumes)
# define validation ops
v_logits = utils.inference(v_images)
accuracy = utils.accuracy(v_logits, v_volumes)

... a bunch of code here ...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    ... more code here ...
    if step % FLAGS.test_interval == 0:
        acc = sess.run([accuracy])
        print('Accuracy on validation data: {}'.format(acc))
    ... more code here ...
```

Is this what you have been looking for?